# tring to convert str string for use in std::getline delimiter

Tags: c++, string, split

im trying to take `std::string` value and use it as delimiter in `std::getline()` function 
but no mater what i do the compiler gives me error.
this is what im trying to do :

```
std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string item;
    std::string delim ="&&=";
    int ssize = delim.size();
    int newssize = ssize+1;
    char del[SSIZE];  // also here when i try gives error
    strcpy(del,delim.c_str());

        char * delrr[1024] = delim.c_str();  //gives error 

        while(std::getline(ss,item,delrr)) {
           elems.push_back(item);
    }
```

the error im getting is always about const char* convertion .

```
 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'char *[1024]'
1>        There are no conversions to array types, although there are conversions to references or pointers to arrays
1>.\UT.cpp(179) : error C2780: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided
1>        d:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\string(527) : see declaration of 'std::getline'
1>.\UT.cpp(179) : error C2784: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &' from 'std::stringstream'
1>        d:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\string(475) : see declaration of 'std::getline'
1>.\UT.cpp(179) : error C2784: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &' from 'std::stringstream'
1>        d:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\string(475) : see declaration of 'std::getline'
1>.\UT.cpp(179) : error C2782: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem)' : template parameter '_Elem' is ambiguous
1>        d:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\string(475) : see declaration of 'std::getline'
1>        could be 'char **'
1>        or       'char'
```

UPDATE:
found the answer:
[How do I tokenize a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23198/C-String-Toolkit-StrTk-Tokenizer

Comment: You probably want *char delrr[1024]* instead of *char * delrr[1024]*

Comment: Please, take a step back, and explain what you really want to do, in English, without referring to any implementation details.

Comment: getting  cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'char [1024]'
if i remove the *

Comment: karl, in the end split function that the delimiter is std::string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third argument of getline() is a char, not a char array. See [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/). You cannot use this function if you need multiple delimiters or a delimiter made of multiple characters.

Use find() and substr().

Comment: Hmm so what can i do to be able to use delimiter bigger then one char?

Comment: Also a problem, but he gets his error before he reaches that line.

Comment: you saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 3):

std::string::c_str() gives you a pointer to a character array. In order to fill a character array with the results of the call to `c_str()` you'll need to use `strcpy()` or `strncpy()` as those actually copy the C style string.

Also, you've declared `delrr` as an array of 1024 character *pointers* rather than 1024 characters, is that really the intent?